# Nginx config: Two domain names for one nodeJS app

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm working on a nodejs application and I want this app to be accessible via two domains (the two domains point to the same app) with nginx, the app is deployed on DigitalOcean droplet so

let's say  I have my app : :port

and domain one: example1.com

and domain two: example2.com

I followed all the steps to set up ssl for one domain and I did the same for the second and here are my config files (they are in sites-available):
config example1.com

```
`server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example1.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl-1/example1.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-1/example1.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers         'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}`
```

config example2.com

```
`
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example2.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl-2/example2.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-2/example2.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers         'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}`
```

example11.com works fine but example2.com not working and google chrome give this warning

[image]

basically, it's saying that the certificate of example2.com was issued for example1.com.

so anyone has an experience setting up two domains with ssl for the same application on nginx help me.

Answer (score 2):

After redoing all the steps over and over I discovered that everything I did was correct just one thing I missed :

I forgot the site-enabled file for the second domain.

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example2 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example2`

and after that everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If it points to the same app, could you redirect? If so, try this:

```
server {
  server_name example2.com;
  return 301 https://example1.com;
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna redirect because I want to my app to be served from both domains.

Comment: are these nginx confs hosted in different servers?